# Add inpunts above table columns

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I need place 2 inputs above 2 columns, as you can see in added wireframe. Table always adapt width by content in its cells, so I don't know how to format these inputs.

I was thinking about caption, but there is no cell slot, only free space above table. Can you give me any advice how to do it?

[image]

Comment: I would just use another tr row above your thead. So the two inputs are just inside a table cell. I could provide a simple example if it's not clear

Comment: @Wimanicesir example will be greate, i am looking for in docs but I can't move with it

Comment: Could you provide the code you already have? Maybe I can adjust it to make it work :)

Comment: Sharing some code that you've already got would be great :) You've tagged this question with [[tag:vuejs]] and [[tag:bootstrap-vue]], so you're probably using the `<b-table>` component, right?

Comment: @zcoop98 yes, b-table